# Block with small width and horizontal scroller

Tags: html, css

I want to make a block filled with a large number of photos in row. Width of web page is always too small, so I want to add a horizontal scrolling.

I made it here: http://jsfiddle.net/49REZ/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="photos">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://photos-ak.sparkpeople.com/nw/4/4/l446472527.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://photos-ak.sparkpeople.com/nw/4/4/l446472527.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://photos-ak.sparkpeople.com/nw/4/4/l446472527.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://photos-ak.sparkpeople.com/nw/4/4/l446472527.jpg"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper ul {
    width: 10000px;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
```

It works fine in Chrome.

But it does not work well in Firefox, because it fairy displays `10000px` block with a lot of free space after photos.

Comment: `list-style-type: none;` might fix it.

Comment: put your css and code here,please, SO wants the answers to be re-useable, so link-free

Comment: @Allendar What has `list-style-type` to do with this?

Comment: @Mr.Alien The OP already removed all basic styles from the list elements. I'm just pointing out the list-style might somehow still be bugging the offsets of the list-items in his case.

Comment: @Allendar Nah Nah, it's of no use here :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien I've seen weirder things happen in cross-browser with (seeming to be) useless styles causing these kind of weird behavior. Just pointing out something for the OP to test :)

Comment: @Allendar it's not helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the css with the following:

```
.wrapper ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49REZ/4/

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about `display: inline-block;` instead `float: left;`, but these distances between pictures looks bad. Is there a way to avoid comments `<!--` between elements?

Comment: There is another hack where you set font-size to 0. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/49REZ/7/

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:
**HTML:**

```
<ul class="images">
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://photos-ak.sparkpeople.com/nw/4/4/l446472527.jpg" width="150" height="150"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://photos-ak.sparkpeople.com/nw/4/4/l446472527.jpg" width="150" height="150"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://photos-ak.sparkpeople.com/nw/4/4/l446472527.jpg" width="150" height="150"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://photos-ak.sparkpeople.com/nw/4/4/l446472527.jpg" width="150" height="150"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://photos-ak.sparkpeople.com/nw/4/4/l446472527.jpg" width="150" height="150"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://photos-ak.sparkpeople.com/nw/4/4/l446472527.jpg" width="150" height="150"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://photos-ak.sparkpeople.com/nw/4/4/l446472527.jpg" width="150" height="150"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
  ul.images {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 500px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  ul.images li {
    display: inline;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKyQQ/)

Answer (score -1):

try to put your 10 000px on another mother component,such as the div, or directly the body

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @wazaminator If I add another wrapper and move that property - it works the same. If I put the property much higher to the DOM - scroller simply does not work.

Comment: @valex actually,I did
well, then I don't know, if some could vote down this answer,so it get to the bottom of answers...